# responsive code not working on table

Tags: html, css

when i resize browse responsive code working but when i open in my mobile or toggle device mode responsive not working. i use media query but its not working on mobile device. i found scroll in mobile device. but in resize browser working fine.

```css
  body {
  background-color: #91ced4;
}
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background-color: #327a81;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.table-users {
  border: 1px solid #327a81;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: calc(100% - 2em);
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td, table th {
  color: #2b686e;
  padding: 10px;
}
table td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table td:last-child {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left;
}
table th {
  background-color: #daeff1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: white;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #edf7f8;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  table, tr, td {
    display: block;
  }

  td:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100px;
  }
  td:not(:first-child) {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 90px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
  td:not(:first-child):before {
    color: #91ced4;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  td:nth-child(2):before {
    content: 'Name:';
  }
  td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: 'Email:';
  }
  td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: 'Phone:';
  }
  td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: 'Comments:';
  }

  tr {
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  tr:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  img {
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: #daeff1;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    width: 100px;
  }

  td:first-child {
    background-color: #c8e7ea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #91ced4;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    width: 100%;
  }
  td:not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  td:not(:first-child):before {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    position: relative;
  }
  td:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
  }

  tr {
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 1px solid #6cbec6;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .table-users {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-users">
   <div class="header">Users</div>
   
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Picture</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th width="230">Comments</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" alt="" /></td>
         <td>Jane Doe</td>
         <td>jane.doe@foo.com</td>
         <td>01 800 2000</td>
         <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2" alt="" /></td>
         <td>John Doe</td>
         <td>john.doe@foo.com</td>
         <td>01 800 2000</td>
         <td>Blanditiis, aliquid numquam iure voluptatibus ut maiores explicabo ducimus neque, nesciunt rerum perferendis, inventore.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9" alt="" /></td>
         <td>Jane Smith</td>
         <td>jane.smith@foo.com</td>
         <td>01 800 2000</td>
         <td> Culpa praesentium unde pariatur fugit eos recusandae voluptas.</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
         <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" alt="" /></td>
         <td>John Smith</td>
         <td>john.smith@foo.com</td>
         <td>01 800 2000</td>
         <td>Aut voluptatum accusantium, eveniet, sapiente quaerat adipisci consequatur maxime temporibus quas, dolorem impedit.</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the viewport tag to your `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: You can read more about this meta tag here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). If you could mark my answer as correct if it helped when you get the opportunity then please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**The width=device-width** part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The **initial-scale=1.0** part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.